# Background Image of Div Working on Code Pen Desktop but Not Working When Opened on Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, background, breakpoints, codepen

On Code Pen, I have a series of divs with background images that are not rendering properly on mobile devices (safari / chrome on iPhone XR is what I'm testing on).

It works perfectly on Code Pen, the backgrounds resize properly as the viewport shrinks and then at my specified break point it switches to mobile-friendly background image, but not at all in reality on the phone.  It feels like it's uber-zooming in on the phone.

Project: https://codepen.io/learntocodequickly/pen/yLaWPKg

```
.first {
    background-image: url(https://learntocodequickly.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/mlk-12-1.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #333333;  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
        .first {
            background-image: url(https://learntocodequickly.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/mlk-12-2.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;  
        }
    }
```

Tried adding the media info into the head (saw that somewhere) and I've tried switching away from cover attribute to 100% width with no luck, I'm not sure where the problem is occurring.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

In the Head settings use  " insert  most common view port meta tag" to automatically add
! Also in your CSS font setting  try  using   5vw instead of 5em. You will need to adjust the number for desktop view . The  vw auto scales down font size when screen  is made smaller.
[codepen settings for  head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jepFl.png)